# Perl: Adding text before filename extension?

Tags: perl

How would I go about appending text to a filename before the extension?

For example,

```
open my $in, '<', $my_file or die $!;

open my $out, '>',"$my_file" or die $!;
```

$my_file looks like this:

```
/this/is/my/directory/blahblah.txt/
```

I want to append it in the output like this:

```
/this/is/my/directory/blahblah_new.txt
or 
new_blahblah.txt
```

Hope thats an okay explanation! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex substitution like so:

```
open my $in, '<', $my_file or die "Cannot open $my_file for reading: $!";
( my $out_file = $my_file ) =~ s{([.]txt)$}{_new$1};
open my $out, '>', $out_file or die "Cannot open $out_file for writing: $!";
```